# is this right way to use PHP switch statement

Tags: php, email, sendmail, switch-statement

hi i'm new to php 
How to send mail to selected city's with diffident email id's with $subject $message $headers

```
$selectcity = array("Bengaluru","Coimbatore","Chennai");                                                                                                         
switch(trim($selectcity))
{
        case "Bengaluru":
        {
        $to = 'one@gmail.com''$subject''$message''$headers';
        break;
        }
        case "Coimbatore":
        {
        $to = 'two@gmail.com''$subject''$message''$headers';
                break;
        }
        case "Chennai":
        {
        $to = 'three@gmail.com''$subject''$message''$headers';
                break;
        }       
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

trim() in PHP does not support array. Inside the switch statement, you should put a selected result, instead of available options.

Reference: http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php

Example:

Assume you have a form to send the select option (e.g. drop-down box in a form):

```
$selected = trim($_POST['ddb_city']);
switch($selected) {
   // the cases
}
```

Also, to send an email, check out mail() function in PHP ( http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php ) . Your current syntax is wrong .

Answer (score 1):

You can't switch on an array. You need to have a specific value to switch on, like an element in the array.

```
$selectcity = array("Bengaluru","Coimbatore","Chennai");                                                                                                         
$i=0;  // this doesn't really make sense in the context, just used for the example
switch(trim($selectcity[$i]))
{
    case "Bengaluru":
      $to = 'one@gmail.com';
      $subject="subject";
      $message="message";
      $headers="test";
      break;

    case "Coimbatore":
      $to = 'two@gmail.com';
      $subject="subject";
      $message="message";
      $headers="test";
      break;
    case "Chennai":
      $to = 'three@gmail.com';
      $subject="subject";
      $message="message";
      $headers="test";
      break;
    default:
      $to = 'four@gmail.com';
      $subject="subject";
      $message="message";
      $headers="test";
}
```

Comment: hey i tried wht u say but its giving error like this Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING on line 6 in example code

Comment: thats because your value quoting is messed up in your `$to` values.

Comment: your statement `$to = 'one@gmail.com''$subject''$message''$headers';` will produce parse errors, it could be something like this  `$to = array('one@gmail.com', $subject, $message, $headers);`, you may accordingly have to change other 3 statements.

Comment: I didn't check your quotes, fixed.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the {} braces inside each case statement. If you're selecting the city from a form, perhaps something like the following will help:

```
<?php
$selectedCity = $_GET['city'];
switch(trim($selectedCity))
{
    case 'Chennai':
        $to = "<contents>";
        break;
    case 'Bengaluru':
        $to = "<contents>";
        break;
    default: // do whatever you want when they've selected something unexpected.

        break;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$selectcity = array_map('trim',array("Bengaluru","Coimbatore","Chennai"));

// the assumiing your value for city is coming form a form and you want to determine 
// address to send to       
switch($_POST['city'];)
{
        case "Bengaluru":
          $to = "'one@gmail.com''$subject''$message''$headers'";
          break;

        case "Coimbatore":
          $to = "'two@gmail.com''$subject''$message''$headers'";
          break;

        case "Chennai":
          $to = "'three@gmail.com''$subject''$message''$headers'";
          break;

}
```